# How to stop the transition animation in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

There is window, its layout designed by `states and transition`.  we know that when the state change, the `transition-animation` will start automatically,  but when the transition animation doesn't finished, i change the state, it make troubles.  just like `slow in reacting`;  how to fix it? thank you...

it something like this :

> Flickable {
>
> ```
>             id: content
>             anchors.fill: parent
>             flickableDirection: Flickable.HorizontalFlick
>             contentWidth: width * 2
>             contentHeight: height
>             clip: true
>
>             onFlickStarted: {
>                 if(horizontalVelocity > 0) {
>                     regAndFind.state = "Find"
>                 }
>                 else {
>                     regAndFind.state = "Register"
>                 }
>             }  ....... 
> }
> ```

```
states: [
    State {
        name: "Register"
        PropertyChanges {
            target: slider
            x: 0
        }
        PropertyChanges {
            target: content
            contentX: 0
        }
    },
    State {
        name: "Find"
        PropertyChanges {
            target: slider
            x: parent.width / 2
        }
        PropertyChanges {
            target: content
            contentX: parent.width
        }
    }
]

transitions: [
    Transition {
        NumberAnimation {
            target: slider
            property: "x"
            duration: 600
        }
        NumberAnimation {
            target: content
            property: "contentX"
            duration: 600
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Read about the [animation element](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animation.html) in Qml.

Before you move to other state, you can call the `Animation::stop ()` function to stop the animation in between. Note that it will stop the animation immediately, and the animation will have no further effect on the property values.